# Different Checksums Values using BlobDownload Client

Tags: java, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am running into a strange issue. I am downloading the same file from my storage account with no problem. However, I am getting different checksum values for each download.  Below is the code I am using. Any reason why that would be? Thanks

```
       BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder().connectionString(connectStr).buildClient();

    BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.getBlobContainerClient("test");

    String fileName ="blob.iso";
    BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.getBlobClient(fileName);

    blobClient.download("path to file");
```

Comment: May I know how you get the checksum? Based on my test they just match.

Comment: I am using linux command sha512sum

Answer (score 0):

Based on my test, the checksums just match.

Here is my code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String connectStr = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=storagetest789;AccountKey=G3************1w==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";
        BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder().connectionString(connectStr).buildClient();
        BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.getBlobContainerClient("pub");
        BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.getBlobClient("azure-cli-2.0.67.msi");
        blobClient.downloadToFile("d:/test/azure-cli-2.0.67.msi",true);
        System.out.println("azure-cli-2.0.67.msi -> " + DigestUtils.md5DigestAsHex(FileUtils.openInputStream(new File("d:/test/azure-cli-2.0.67.msi"))));
    }
```

I ran it twice, and got the following outputs:

```
// First time
azure-cli-2.0.67.msi -> 4510dc9ee0dd38bfbf261f6a9e467d34
// Second time
azure-cli-2.0.67.msi -> 4510dc9ee0dd38bfbf261f6a9e467d34
```

I see that you are trying to download an ISO file whose size may be larger. I am not sure if it would be a problem. When the network environment is not good, the downloaded data may be incomplete or incorrect which may cause your problem.

Comment: blobClient.downloadToFile("d:/test/azure-cli-2.0.67.msi",true);
I am getting an error that function only takes 1 argument

Comment: @the_greeny_maven Check your `azure-storage-blob` version. Currently, the latest version is 12.4.0. And `downloadToFile` has an overload which takes 2 arguments. Check the source: [public BlobProperties downloadToFile(String filePath, boolean overwrite)](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/3450557166cd27fffe2fdb77c049546dbba8c7e1/sdk/storage/azure-storage-blob/src/main/java/com/azure/storage/blob/specialized/BlobClientBase.java#L478)

Comment: @the_greeny_maven I use `sha1sum` and get the same result as I got from java. `sha512sum` will not be a problem then.